# right div must have a maximum height of the left div?

Tags: html, css

I have a parent container with two floating child divs. The left div will contain a responsive slider and the right div will contain text.

What I want is for the right container to have a maximum height which is consistent with the left div. Basically, what I want is an "overflow:hidden" effect. Anything that can make the right box grow taller than the left box must be cut of/not shown.

Overflow:hidden would have worked if I was using set heights, but I'm not. How can I acheive the same effect with a fluid height? So that the right box never grows taller than the left box....

Comment: Can you use javascript?

Comment: I'd prefer not... I have read a lot of mixed comments on the internet regarding the stats of how many people has javascript disabled... and I still don't know if I should worry about it or not. Some say "no", others say "definitly". If someone has it disabled it would look totally crap if the right box grow larger than the left...

Comment: if someone had js disabled, your slider wouldn't work. Neither would most of the rest of the web. In my opinion, I wouldn't worry about that unless it was going to make essential information impossible to view. But you're just talking about changing the height of a box.

Comment: ok, i will try this and see how will it works. what javascript option is there for this to work?

Comment: google, facebook, twitter, and basically every other website use JS. People who have JS disabled are used to nothing working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If javascript is a possibility, You could use the following css:

```
.left, .right {
    padding:1%;
}
.left {
    background: #ddd;
    float:left;
    width:73%;
}
.right {
    width: 23%;
    background: #bbb;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

and javascript (with jquery):

```
jQuery(function($){

    function resizeRight(){
        $('.right').height( $('.left').height() );
    };

    resizeRight();

    // let's ensure the sizes stay in sync if the user resizes their window
    $(window).resize( function() {
        resizeRight();
    });

});
```

Here's a fiddle with the example: http://jsfiddle.net/nr4zrcjw/1/

---

### Plain Javascript Version

If you don't jquery for anything else, don't include it just for this. Instead you can use this script:

```
var resizeRight = function resizeRight(){
    var r = document.getElementById('right-col')
    var l = document.getElementById('left-col')

    r.style.height = l.offsetHeight + 'px';
    console.log( l.style.paddingTop );

}

var addEvent = function(elem, type, eventHandle) {
    if (elem == null || typeof(elem) == 'undefined') return;
    if ( elem.addEventListener ) {
        elem.addEventListener( type, eventHandle, false );
    } else if ( elem.attachEvent ) {
        elem.attachEvent( "on" + type, eventHandle );
    } else {
        elem["on"+type]=eventHandle;
    }
};
addEvent(window,'resize',resizeRight);

resizeRight();
```

Seen here; http://jsfiddle.net/g689bupe/1/

Comment: thank you jake i will try this. what is the 1% padding for on the left and right containers? can i remove it?

Comment: @Elisha, sure. That was just for the demo. All you really need is the `overflow:hidden`, the `width`s and the `float`s. Also, if you are not already including jquery, it might be silly to include it just for this. I am working on a regular javascript example if that'd help.

Comment: hey Jake, thank you so much for all the help! this works perfectly ;) i already had jquery included as i'm working with wordpress... but what is usually best? jquery or regular javascript? you're awesome, thanx a lot.

Comment: Well if you're already including jquery, you might as well just use that.

Comment: I have a small problem with this code now. But not sure if it's maybe that it's intefering with something else... I'm in firefox. When I make the viewport smaller, then maximize it, and refresh it after maximizing it, the containers grow insanely high. Then I have to navigate to another page first, and then go back to the homepage before it displayes correctly. Just normal resizing of the viewport is fine, but the moment I do it in the order of minimize, maximize, refresh, the heights just go insane.... I would show you a link but i'm on localhost....

Comment: i don't know why the hell that just acted out, but seems to be fine again... hopefully that's gonna stay that way lol. just moved the jquery into the head... i guess that maybe fixed it...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a CSS solution if the right container can have a fixed width.

```css
#parent {
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}

.slider-container {
    border:5px solid blue;
    margin-right:210px;
}

.shrinkable {
    border:5px solid red;
    width:200px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
    <div class="slider-container">
        Remove text from me to see the right column shrink.
        Remove text from me to see the right column shrink. 
        Remove text from me to see the right column shrink. 
        Remove text from me to see the right column shrink. 
        Remove text from me to see the right column shrink. 
        Remove text from me to see the right column shrink.
        Remove text from me to see the right column shrink.
        Remove text from me to see the right column shrink.
        Remove text from me to see the right column shrink.
         
    </div>
    <div class="shrinkable">
        The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain. 
        The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain.
        The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain.
        The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain.
        The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain.
        The rain in spain falls mainly on the plain.
    </div>
</div>
```